# Secondary Page does not load using Flask and Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to wrap my head around flask development, and have created some basic use cases...however, i've hit this snag.

Running locally I am able to run a flask script that renders an input screen for capturing some data, and upon selecting Submit that data is fetched and processed through a function that outputs collected JSON on a new path called /process.

However, when I create a wsgi file, and update my wsgi.conf for apache on the server where this is hosted, only my initial index screen loads, and upon selecting submit the next page now returns the error 'The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.'

here's route for the process page:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['GET','POST'])
def process_inputs():
    user = request.form['user']
    password = request.form['password']
    accountNumber = request.form['account_number']
    companyCode = request.form['company_code']
    docCode = request.form['doc_code']
    env = request.form['environment']
    user_login = f'{user}.admin%{accountNumber}'


    data = audit_transaction(user_login,password,companyCode,docCode,env)
    return render_template('results.html', data=data)
```

I've added two aliases to the wsgi config path, that resulted in reloading the index upon selecting submit.

conf snippet:

WSGIScriptAlias /audit_transaction C:/scripts_mains/audit_trace_doccode_track/wsgi_script/wsgi_script.wsgi
<Directory C:/scripts_mains/audit_trace_doccode_track>
Require all granted

Comment: The problem is in the server config, not the flask code

Comment: the reference snippet used in the config is:
above
the two paths, i'll say one is audit_transaction and the other is process exist in the same flask file, how would i create two alias paths for them?

Comment: I'm not proud of it but i did just retrun my data dump on the same rendered initial index instead of generating a new page, it will work for now.